# How I can get bitpay.pri and bitpay.pub files

Tags: php, bitcoin, bitpay

I am using Bitcoin payment Gateway. I have cloned repositry from https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client and also made account on https://test.bitpay.com. I am using TestNet as well.

In Git repsositry https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client I can see

```
$privateKey = new \Bitpay\PrivateKey('/tmp/bitpay.pri');
```

But I could not get bitpay.pri and bitpay.pub neither in git repositry nor in https://test.bitpay.com. In documentation also, I could not figure out how and from where I can get it. Right now, It is throwing error because of these 2 missing files.

Any suggestions, how I can get these files?

Answer (score -1):

It just path where these keys will be save/generated.
Read this [tutorial](http://help.bitpay.com/businesses-and-organizations/implementation-and-development/bitpay-php-library-usage-tutorial-from-start-creating-keys-to-finish-creating-an-invoice)